# Pandas To_sql out-of-range error

Tags: python, pandas, outofrangeexception

I am importing json data from an api into a pandas data frame and from the data frame I'm using pandas.to_sql to put it into a sql database.

Some rows from the API have invalid data that causes an out-of-range error.

Is there a way to skip or drop those rows rather failing the program?

The error is coming from trying to insert '1900-01-01T00:00:00Z' into a datetime field in SQL.

---

Error Response: DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. (242) (SQLExecDirectW)') [SQL: 'INSERT INTO [TEMP_well_origin] ([Abstract], [Basin], [Confidential], [ConfidentialDate], [Country], [County], [CreatedDate], [CurrentOperator], [CurrentStatus], [CurrentStatusDate], [DeletedDate], [DepthUom], [District], [ElevRefDatum], [ElevRefDatumepsgCode], [ElevUom], [Environment], [Field], [FluidType], [Formation], [GovernmentID], [GroundElev], [InitialClassification], [LeaseName], [LeaseNumber], [LicenseDate], [OnProductionDate], [OriginalOperator], [PermitNumber], [ProvinceState], [Range], [RangeDirection], [Region], [Remark], [Section], [Source], [SpudDate], [Township], [TownshipDirection], [UID], [UpdatedDate], [WaterDepth], [WaterDepthDatum], [WellName], [WellNumber], [Wgs84Latitude], [Wgs84Longitude]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ((None, 'ANADARKO BASIN', 'N', None, 'UNITED STATES', 'KINGFISHER', '2017-06-14T17:53:36.853Z', 'GASTAR EXPL', 'PERMITTED', '2017-06-13T00:00:00Z', None, 'ft', None, 'MSL', 5714, 'ft', None, 'UNKNOWN', 'OIL & GAS', 'WOODFORD', 3507325671, 1121.0, None, 'STOWEY 1907', None, '2017-06-13T00:00:00Z', None, None, 'TEMP25671A', 'OKLAHOMA', 7.0, 'W', 'NORTH AMERICA', None, 14.0, 'DI', None, 19.0, 'N', 18965913, '2018-04-13T21:06:55.96Z', None, 'MSL', 'STOWEY 1907', '11-1LOH', 36.1304886, -97.9171516), (None, 'ANADARKO BASIN', 'N', None, 'UNITED STATES', 'KINGFISHER', '2017-06-14T17:53:36.853Z', 'MARATHON OIL', 'ACTIVE', '2017-07-19T00:00:00Z', None, 'ft', None, 'MSL', 5714, 'ft', None, 'UNKNOWN', 'OIL', 'MISSISSIPPIAN', 3507325669, 1088.0, None, 'WHITE 1607', 732191770.0, '2017-06-12T00:00:00Z', '2017-08-01T00:00:00Z', None, 'TEMP25669', 'OKLAHOMA', 7.0, 'W', 'NORTH AMERICA', None, 13.0, 'DI', '2017-06-19T00:00:00Z', 16.0, 'N', 18965897, '2017-11-23T10:44:37.41Z', None, 'MSL', 'WHITE 1607', '1-130H', 35.8707209, -97.9037809), (None, 'ANADARKO BASIN', 'N', None, 'UNITED STATES', 'ELLIS', '2017-06-14T17:53:36.853Z', 'JONES ENERGY', 'P & A', '1900-01-01T00:00:00Z', None, 'ft', None, 'MSL', 5714, 'ft', None, 'UNKNOWN', 'OIL & GAS', 'CLEVELAND', 3504523668, 2422.0, None, 'OBLANDER 28', None, '2017-06-13T00:00:00Z', None, None, 'TEMP23668', 'OKLAHOMA', 25.0, 'W', 'NORTH AMERICA', None, 28.0, 'DI', '2017-07-03T00:00:00Z', 20.0, 'N', 18965889, '2018-03-22T08:55:31.79Z', None, 'MSL', 'OBLANDER 28', '1H', 36.1866636, -99.8803567), (None, 'ANADARKO BASIN', 'N', None, 'UNITED STATES', 'BLAINE', '2017-06-14T17:53:36.853Z', 'CHESAPEAKE', 'INACTIVE', '2017-08-20T00:00:00Z', None, 'ft', None, 'MSL', 5714, 'ft', None, 'UNKNOWN', 'OIL', 'MISSISSIPPIAN', 3501123814, 1388.0, None, 'NUGGET 34-20-12', 932192050.0, '2017-06-13T00:00:00Z', None, None, 'TEMP23814', 'OKLAHOMA', 12.0, 'W', 'NORTH AMERICA', None, 34.0, 'DI', '2017-06-24T00:00:00Z', 20.0, 'N', 18965888, '2017-12-04T10:37:36.05Z', None, 'MSL', 'NUGGET 34-20-12', '1HC', 36.1591637, -98.475103), (None, 'CHAUTAUQUA PLATFORM', 'N', None, 'UNITED STATES', 'PAYNE', '2017-06-14T17:53:36.853Z', 'WHITE STAR PETR ', 'INACTIVE', '2017-06-12T00:00:00Z', None, 'ft', None, 'MSL', 5714, 'ft', None, 'PRAIRIE VIEW EAST', 'OIL', 'MISSISSIPPIAN', 3511924431, 1111.0, None, 'BETTY JEAN 26-19N-1W', 1192192560.0, '2017-06-12T00:00:00Z', None, None, 'TEMP24431', 'OKLAHOMA', 1.0, 'W', 'NORTH AMERICA', None, 26.0, 'DI', '2017-08-04T00:00:00Z', 19.0, 'N', 18965882, '2017-12-04T10:37:36.05Z', None, 'MSL', 'BETTY JEAN 26-19N-1W', '2MH', 36.087479, -97.2757837), (None, 'CHAUTAUQUA PLATFORM', 'N', None, 'UNITED STATES', 'PAYNE', '2017-06-14T17:53:36.853Z', 'WHITE STAR PETR ', 'INACTIVE', '2017-06-12T00:00:00Z', None, 'ft', None, 'MSL', 5714, 'ft', None, 'PRAIRIE VIEW EAST', 'OIL', 'MISSISSIPPIAN', 3511924430, 1113.0, None, 'BETTY JEAN 26-19N-1W', 1192192550.0, '2017-06-12T00:00:00Z', None, None, 'TEMP24430', 'OKLAHOMA', 1.0, 'W', 'NORTH AMERICA', None, 26.0, 'DI', '2017-07-24T00:00:00Z', 19.0, 'N', 18965881, '2018-05-30T09:36:45.16Z', None, 'MSL', 'BETTY JEAN 26-19N-1W', '1MH', 36.087479, -97.2758829), (None, 'ANADARKO BASIN', 'N', None, 'UNITED STATES', 'KINGFISHER', '2017-06-14T17:53:36.853Z', 'NEWFIELD EXPL', 'ACTIVE', '2017-08-06T00:00:00Z', None, 'ft', None, 'MSL', 5714, 'ft', None, 'OKARCHE NORTH', 'OIL', 'MISSISSIPPIAN', 3507325668, 1156.0, None, 'ROBERT', 732191660.0, '2017-06-12T00:00:00Z', '2017-08-01T00:00:00Z', None, 'TEMP25668', 'OKLAHOMA', 7.0, 'W', 'NORTH AMERICA', None, 21.0, 'DI', '2017-06-13T00:00:00Z', 15.0, 'N', 18965765, '2018-03-22T08:55:31.79Z', None, 'MSL', 'ROBERT', '1507 1H-21', 35.7557449, -97.9433457), (None, 'SOUTH OKLAHOMA FOLDED BELT', 'N', None, 'UNITED STATES', 'CARTER', '2017-06-14T17:53:36.853Z', 'AVALON OPERATING LLC', 'PERMITTED', '2017-06-14T00:00:00Z', None, 'ft', None, 'MSL', 5714, 'ft', None, 'UNKNOWN', 'OIL & GAS', 'HUNTON (LS CHIMNEY HILL)', 3501926276, 958.0, None, 'DOC BROWN', None, '2017-06-14T00:00:00Z', None, None, 'TEMP26276', 'OKLAHOMA', 2.0, 'W', 'NORTH AMERICA', None, 30.0, 'DI', None, 3.0, 'S', 18965755, '2018-04-13T21:06:55.96Z', None, 'MSL', 'DOC BROWN', '2-30-19XH', 34.2629504, -97.4414937)  ... displaying 10 of 1000 total bound parameter sets ...  (None, 'CHAUTAUQUA PLATFORM', 'N', None, 'UNITED STATES', 'PAYNE', '2017-01-29T02:24:26.803Z', '(N/A)', 'INACTIVE', None, None, 'ft', None, 'MSL', 5714, 'ft', None, 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', '(N/A)', 3511902537, 888.94, None, 'CATES', None, None, None, None, None, 'OKLAHOMA', 5.0, 'E', 'NORTH AMERICA', None, 32.0, 'DI', None, 18.0, 'N', 18951364, '2018-05-30T09:36:45.16Z', None, 'MSL', 'CATES', '1-A', 35.996081, -96.79559), (None, 'CHAUTAUQUA PLATFORM', 'N', None, 'UNITED STATES', 'WAGONER', '2017-01-29T02:24:26.803Z', '(N/A)', 'INACTIVE', None, None, 'ft', None, 'MSL', 5714, 'ft', None, 'UNKNOWN', 'UNKNOWN', '(N/A)', 3514505289, 527.91, None, 'SHAFFER', None, None, None, None, None, 'OKLAHOMA', 17.0, 'E', 'NORTH AMERICA', None, 1.0, 'DI', None, 16.0, 'N', 18951363, '2018-05-30T09:36:45.16Z', None, 'MSL', 'SHAFFER', '1', 35.8872222, -95.4483611))] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/9h9h)

Comment: could you please show the sample row for understanding the invalid data

Comment: I've added the rows and original data to the first post.

Comment: I think the best solution would be to insert the data in a nvarchar data type instead of date time it could be temporary table also and then you can write a procedure in sql server to transform and insert the data into date time field.

Comment: Or you can also convert the date according to your database date time format before inserting it to the database.